# azure functions send data to AWS topic SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-functions, amazon-sns

In azure, we have service bus topics and azure functions listen to this topic. If there is any data into this topic, function will be triggered. I want to send the data to AWS topic. AWS has C# SDK, but we need to setup appconfig. How can we set appconfig in Azure function, or there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient (string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey)` [constructor option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SNS/TSNSClient.html) and store the key and secret as App Settings (or if you want, use Key Vault). You don't need to use `app.config` to store secrets (and you should generally avoid it! Checking in secrets is a bad thing)

Comment: thanks very much. iI use this one
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient (string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey,RegionEndpoint).

Comment: makes sense, let me know if you run into any issues there

Comment: i want to assembly #r "AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService" in azure functions. However i got error CS0006: Metadata file 'AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService' could not be found

Comment: @Lawrencesong please mark this as the answer if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Lawrencesong - you need to make sure you add that via your package.json first. Open a new question if you need more assistance on loading that package (but I'd encourage you to google it first since we have good docs on it)

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Thanks. I found the way to add the reference